# Pseudo code conversion into python for csv

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have some pseudocode that I am trying to convert into Python and was hoping for some help. I have a csv that I would like to import into Python and essentially split up into smaller csv's based on a conditional statement. I have an example of the spreadsheet structure and how the split looks. I was thinking the best way was to create a for loop and iterate through each row?

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

for i in file['col8']:
    if i != 0:
        then add to array that gets converted to csv1
        (would this iterate through, skip the zeros, then go to 
         the next block of non-zeros?)
```

[image: example imag]

Comment: use a boolean flag like `collecting` within the loop. Then you would have a 4-way conditional inside the loop using `collecting` and `i=0`.  One block would start collection and set the flag true, one block would write out the collection and set the flag false, one block would continue collection, and one would basically do nothing.   I'm not here to write the code for you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @RufusVS idea from comments:

```
# create dataframe
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
                    'B': [0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,4,5,5,0,0]})
foo['C'] = 0 # add new column with 0s

group = 0
collecting = False #boolean flag
for i in range(foo.shape[0]):
  if foo['B'][i] != 0:
    if not collecting:
      collecting = True
      group += 1 # increment for every new group
    foo['C'][i] = group
  else:
    if collecting:
      collecting = False

bar = foo.groupby('C') # groupby to get different sets

bar.get_group(0) # group with all 0s
bar.get_group(1) # group with first set
bar.get_group(2) # group with second set
```